# How to select the highest sum of value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

I have the table like this

```
id    rate_user_id   content_id     points  category_id
1      100              1                  5      1
2      101              1                  3      1
3      100              2                  8      1
4      103              2                  11     1
```

So I want to looking highest point of content in this  category 1

Content_id 2 = 19 points .

Answer (score 1):

U can do this by

select content_id,sum(points) from user group by content_id order by sum(points) desc limit 1;

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Hiren, I got it from your answer

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the command MAX.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT MAX(Pts) FROM
    (SELECT SUM(points) Pts GROUP BY content_id) A
```